# React Model Scrolls to the bottom when opened

Tags: reactjs, forms, autoscroll

I wrote a react model which has few text boxes and buttons, which when opens automatically goes(scrolls) to the bottom of the model.

Comment: code or sandbox?

Comment: Yeah, it is code.

Comment: show your code, link or sandbox ;)